# Why the bias distribution in the last layer is always close to symmetric?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to train a very simple model, the first layer is full connection, while the output layer output 2 values to represent different categories.

```
  def inference(self, features_pl):
    tensor_dict = {}
    # Define a scope for reusing the variables
    with tf.variable_scope("cnn"):
      layer1_output = tf.layers.dense(features_pl,
                                      512,
                                      activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                      kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.01, stddev=0.001),
                                      bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                                      name="layer1")
      logits = tf.layers.dense(layer1_output,
                               2,
                               activation=None,
                               kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.01, stddev=0.001),
                               bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(),
                               name="output_layer")
```

I found the output layer's value (kernel + bias) are always looks symmetric.

I had printed the weight in the model, the sum of kernel and bias in very close to the initial value while we can see the distribution changed a lot in the tensorboard.

Did anyone here has the similar experience about this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the logit value for class 1 by some quantity is equivalent to decreasing the logit value for class 2 by the same quantity, and vice versa. You can intuitively see that the gradient of the loss wrt the two logits is therefore symmetric, and therefore the gradient wrt to the weights would also be symmetric, causing this effect.

Comment: Make sense! Is this a common case that actually we don’t need to any thing to resolve? Or is there any other optimizations will should apply?

Comment: @Capemer I don't think it's anything that needs to be resolved